# Elasticsearch with snowball analyzer only returns results for stemmed word

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the snowball analyzer in my query string search ... like so

```
   "query" : {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : the-query-string-goes-here,
        "default_operator" : "AND",
        "analyzer" : "snowball"
      }
    }
```

this actually works but it does something weird ... searching for "fighting" will return results for "fight" but ignore results for "fighting". A search for "crews" will return results for "crew" but not "crews", also a search for "crew" also ignores results for "crews" ...

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Have you solved? May I know if my answer was useful?

Comment: I set the default analyzer to be snowball and that took care of it, but I still don't understand why just setting it in the query string didn't work. How is the indexing different that a search for fighting in one case (default analyzer set to snowball) can actually pull up the "fighting" post but the other (just specifying it in the query string) doesn't.

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer, if you apply stemming only at query time you end up searching for stems within a field which hasn't been stemmed while indexing. Glad you've solved!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stemming makes sense when you apply it at both index time and query time. Now you are applying it at query time, so that you search for the stems of the words which are part of the query.
But I guess the index doesn't contain the stems since you haven't applied stemming at index time. You're actually searching on the `_all` field since you didn't specify any field name neither in your query nor using `default_field` (or `fields`) attribute supported by the query_string. The `_all` field is by default analyzed using the `StandardAnalyzer`.

There are different ways to solve this problem. I'd personally decide a set of fields on which you want to search in your query and apply to them stemming in your mapping. After that you don't need to specify the analyzer in your query since the configured analyzer for the field on which you are searching will be used.

Let me know if the answer is clear enough.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. But why would it ignore an item that's an exact match to the query? (ie a search for "fighting" doesn't return a post titled "fighting" but it returns a post titled "fight")

Comment: because when you apply stemming to the query fighting becomes fight. You're really searching for fight instead of fighting. ;)

Comment: so that means my problem still would exist even if I used the stemmer on index? How do I make it so that it does a search both on the stemmed word and the actual query .... Sphinx does this automatically, kinda surprised by the implementation here

Comment: I explained it in my answer: if you change your mapping and apply stemming then it will be applied at both index time and query time: when you index fighting you actually index fight, and when you search for fighting you actually search for fight. That's how stemming works, and that's why it gives you more results.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @javanna for pointing me in the right direction. I solved this by setting the analyzer for the `_all` field to `snowball`. See [this doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/all-field.html) for details.

I'm using the Ruby tire gem, and I was able to specify the mapping in my model as follows:

```
mapping(_all: { analyzer: 'snowball' }) do
  indexes :id, type: 'integer'
  indexes :description
  indexes :name, boost: 10
end
```

I formatted my query exactly like in the original question.